# How to deal with deleted event classes in event sourcing

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am trying to implement a pure event sourced service to see where I will get problems. Now I found a problem that I can not solve so far, so I would like to open a discussion about it.

Given the following aggregate:

```
class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public void Apply(UserNameChangedEvent domainEvent)
        {
            Name = domainEvent.NewName;
        }


        public void Apply(UserCreatedEvent domainEvent)
        {
            Name = domainEvent.Name;
            Id = domainEvent.Id;
        }
    }
```

and those Domain Events

```
class UserCreatedEvent
    {
        public string NewName { get; }
        public Guid Id { get; }

        public UserCreatedEvent(string newName, Guid id)
        {
            NewName = newName;
            Id = id;
        }
    }

class UserNameChangedEvent
    {
        public string NewName { get; }

        public UserNameChangedEvent(string newName)
        {
            NewName = newName;
        }
    }
```

Lets say I create a user and change its name to "Peter" afterwards, then I have a `UserCretedEvent` and a `UserChangedNameEvent` persisted in my EventStore. Now the business says that changing a name is no longer possible and therefore I would remove the class `UserChangedNameEvent` and the function that handles it. But now I have the problem that I can not recreate the aggregate in its correct state, which would be with the name "Peter".

Of course I could start hacking around and mark the function and class as deprecated, so I could keep using it, but I might end up with a lot of event classes afterwards and this will be a nightmare to keep track of. I also heard you might create a new event that persists the change in the domain, but that also seems very hacky to me and not a very good style, as this is no domain event in my point of view.

So the question is, how do I deal the best with changes like this?

edit: just to clarify: I do not want to delete any event, just the class and the function where I use it, as the requirement is different now.

Comment: I would be very interested in how you handled this issue :)

Answer (score 3):

THE resource for questions related to changes in event schemas is [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning), by Greg Young.

> So the question is, how do I deal the best with changes like this?

It depends on the real problem that you are trying to solve.

If the requirement is that users aren't allowed to change their names in the future, then you take away the logic in the domain model that creates *new* `UserNameChangedEvent`s, but leave behind the correct processing where the events do appear.

If the requirement is that changes to user names should be ignored, then you also take the `Apply(UserNameChanged)` handler and turn it into a NoOp, just as you would for any other unrecognized event.

If the requirement is that information about name changes should be destroyed, then you migrate your event store to a new schema, that no longer includes the `UserNameChanged` event.

It may help to think through how you would solve the problem if you were storing your state in an RDBMS: is it enough to ignore the User Name column? do you need to delete the column? Do you need to (somehow) restore value in a column to a previously written value?

Knowing the problem in a traditional database that is analogous to the problem you want to solve in the event store should help identify the appropriate solution.

Also: pay attention to whether or not your domain model is the system of record for the data that needs changed, or if instead you are caching a representation of information published by a different authority.

Comment: "...but leave behind the correct processing where the events do appear". Ok but this means that I have a event class and a function in my domain that I only need because I do not have a snapshot like in a database oriented persistence solution.
The requirement is, that the command handler is removed, so my application does not offer a way to change a users name. But I would still have to keep this in my domain so I can replay and recreate the objects later, right? This just does not seem like a good approach to me, businessrules change frequently an this might become a lot of unused classes.

Comment: thanks fo the link though, I will read it next week on vacations ;)

Comment: "...It may help to think through how you would solve the problem if you were storing your state in an RDBMS: is it enough to ignore the User Name column? do you need to delete the column?..."
I would just delete the command handler, and the function that changes the name in the domain. There would ne no Database Changes or Migrations whatsoever.

Comment: Maintaining code that handled old versions of the app is one of the basic trade-offs in doing event sourcing. Also, why I can't see it as worth the pain and risk for most apps.

Answer (score 1):

Events captured facts about the system. If User name was changed at some point, it is a fact. Future business rule changes cannot affect past facts.
So you should not remove UserNameChanged events, and all associated handlers, events are there, and you should not rewrite past history.

In CQRS app, events are generated by command handlers. So this is a place where you specify business requirements. "Now the business says that changing a name is no longer possible" means that ChangeName command is no longer available: you can simply remove it, or just throw an error saying that you cannot change names anymore.

Comment: I do not want to delete a event, just the class and the location I use it (for example the command handler). But when I do that, I will never be able to recreate the object in its correct form (see post). That is the problem here ;)

Comment: What I'm trying to say - you cannot remove event handling code, you can only remove or forbid the command. Not sure why it is a problem.

Comment: Ok, than I might have gotten you wrong. It is just that I despise having code in my domain that is there because of my persistence layer, e.g. an apply method for an event that is not generatable anymore. I have the feeling that this might lead to a lot of apply methods that are not used in production and are only existing because of legacy reasons. This just does not seem right to me...

Comment: @Simons0n, I totally agree with you, and actually you shouldn't have apply(changeName) method, the problem is in the code(framework or whatever) you depend on not in eventsourcing for this case, events that aren't handled should produce a log message or even error and the code itself just returns same state and ignores it, so you don't even have to have such method in your code. Having all previous code is unreasonable crazy fanaticism about ES

Comment: But even the framwork would need to know how the old event would have to be handled, because you still want the name from the initial state. Whatever it is, it will generate some bloat ware somewhere. An error/log is also not right, as you would still need the correct name.